# ASP.NET Core 2.0 service life time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I have api application ,service & repository class library application . Service part i write business logic and repository only communicate for database. My question which type of dependency is best for repository and service .

```
services.AddScoped<ITicketRepository, TicketRepository>();
services.AddTransient<ITicketRepository, TicketRepository>();
services.AddSingleton<ITicketRepository, TicketRepository>();
```

Comment: If there's choices it must depend, so what's the scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Like always, it depends. My suggestion is the following:

- Scoped: in my opinion, there can be two main reasons for using this:

  - Your dependency has a dependency which has a scoped lifetime. In this case, you cannot use singleton, but can use scoped or transient. Which one you should take is based on the other criteria.
  - Your dependency has some state which makes it unsuitable to be used in singleton scope, but it is heavyweight enough that you don't want to register it as transient. Another possibility is that, again, it cannot be used in singleton scope, but it is fine to share the same instance per request (scope) and you don't want to add the overhead of constructing new ones if two types depend on the same thing and both of them are used to serve a single request.
- Transient: this is the simplest approach. Every time an instance of a dependency registered in this manner is required, a new instance is created. This is probably the most foolproof, but can cause serious overhead if its usage is not justified. @Tony Ngo pointed out in his answer, quoting from the official docs, that this works best for lightweight, stateless objects, but I'd argue that statelessness is a very good indicator that you may want to use singleton lifetime as statelessness guarantees that the same object can be used concurrently just fine. Whether you choose transient or singleton lifetime in this case really depends whether you care about such aspects of performance like GC cost, which is obviously much, much higher if you create a new instance every time such a dependency is required, even if you could avoid doing so. Having said that, transient is used by many developers in this scenario as well, probably due to its foolproofness, or simply because they tend to think about it as the default choice.
- Singleton: the points above basically summarize this one: you can choose this when there is absolutely no reason to create a new instance of the dependency for each request (scope) or to use an other dependent instance. Note that like said before, you cannot use singleton lifetime when the type has a dependency which is registered as scoped.

Answer (score 0):

> Transient lifetime services (AddTransient) are created each time
>   they're requested from the service container. This lifetime works best
>   for lightweight, stateless services.
>
> Scoped lifetime services (AddScoped) are created once per client
>   request (connection).
>
> Singleton lifetime services (AddSingleton) are created the first time
>   they're requested (or when Startup.ConfigureServices is run and an
>   instance is specified with the service registration).

So depend on what you need you can choose correct liftetime you can view it more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your `TicketRepository` is depend on your EF Core `DbContext` and your
EF Core `DbContext` is by default registered as [`ScopedSerivce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#implicitly-sharing-dbcontext-instances-across-multiple-threads-via-dependency-injection)  so here registering `TicketRepository` as `SingletonService` is out of consideration as because:

> It's dangerous to resolve a scoped service from a singleton. It may cause the service to have incorrect state when processing subsequent requests.

For more details: [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core-Service lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#service-lifetimes)

Now you can choose between `AddTransient<>` and  `AddScoped<>` where:

> Transient lifetime services (AddTransient) are created each time they're requested from the service container. This lifetime works best for lightweight, stateless services.
>
> Scoped lifetime services (AddScoped) are created once per client request (connection).